# KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: - Asked to remove non-existent executor

Tags: apache-spark

Getting this error when submitting spark job to run on kubernetes cluster.

```
2018-12-21 21:54:28 INFO  ExecutorPodsAllocator:54 - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
2018-12-21 21:54:29 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 74 requested
2018-12-21 21:54:29 INFO  KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 74
2018-12-21 21:54:29 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 74 from BlockManagerMaster.
```

It just keeps going indefinitely.

The executor pod fails and removed after creation so no way to recover the failure reason. Can someone help to troubleshoot the issue.